# Display hide-expanding dynamic hierarchical tree structure in php and jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have following preorder traversal table:

```
name           id   unitid  lft rgt level   depth
Language        1   001     1   22  0       0
web             95  3       2   23  1       1
html            97  2       3   24  2       2
css             96  1       5   26  2       3
java            94  2       8   29  1       4
struts         100  1       9   30  2       5
php             93  1       12  33  1       6
codeigniter     99  2       13  34  2       7
zend            98  1       15  36  2       8
```

I want to display tree structure of it with the help of php and jquery. Jquery for maintaining dynamic tree structure so that I can hide and expand the child and parents. Is there any jquery plugin available for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the TreeMenu.js and follow their documentation. Download the plugin and embed it with your code.

http://mackpexton.com/projects/TreeMenu/index.htm

Its easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with Tree Grid functionality of [jQuery Easy UI](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php) plugin.

Comment: Ok..that is jquery part but how to display it dynamically using PHP with the help of ul li tags

Comment: Have you seen its documentation part ? They have show its use with php very brilliantly..http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation

Comment: Can it possible to use these documentation for displaying preorder traversal table in jquery.